# Can't get selected value from dropdown in PHP, SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following code:

```
<form action="MovieDatabase.php" method='post'>
  <select name="director_movie">
    <?php 

        $sql = mysqli_query($mysql, "SELECT DISTINCT Title FROM Film2");

        while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){

    ?>
    <option value="director_movie1" id="film_id"><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></option>

    <?php
    // close while loop 
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

For the drop-down, which uses the values from SQL table. So the drop-down has values as movie titles.

When I try to access the selected value from **MovieDatabase.php** like that:

```
$_POST['director_movie'];
```

and when I try to echo it, it only shows me option value **direcotr_movie1** which is not what I'm looking for. In this case I want to get the title of the movie, which was selected from the dropdown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All your options have the same value (`director_movie1`). Use the ID fetched from the database for each row.

Comment: when you use $_POST['some_name'].. you get whatever is set in `value=`... if you want movie title then set `value=$row['Title']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hard-coded ***same value*** for ***each option*** in your code in this line:-

```
<option value="director_movie1" id="film_id"><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></option>
```

That's why you are ***getting same-value every time***.

***Change it to below:-***

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['Title'];?>"><?php echo $row['Title'];?></option>
```

Now it will work fine.

Note:- `id` need to be unique for each HTML element so remove that repetitive `id` (i don't think you have any need of that)

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @anthony  glad to help you.Cheers :):)

Comment: @AlivetoDie i have successfully fetched client_name in dropdown & now i want to show client_village in textbox based on selected dropdown value. how ?

Comment: @shubhamshah  by asking a new question with proper inputs and your code effort. Asking new questions in comment is not a good idea. You can reference me the link, If i have time i will try to answer you there.Thanks

Comment: @AlivetoDie here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602131/fill-textbox-on-dropdown-selection-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<option value="director_movie1" id="film_id"><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></option>
```

to

```
<option value=<?php echo $row['Title']; ?> id="film_id"><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are hardcoding your value `<option value="director_movie1" id="film_id">` and wondering why your form submits your hardcoded value?

The movie title that is shown in your select is just what the users can see. your form submits what you put into `value=<your required information here>`

On another note: Using the title as the field might result in problems when using anything but chars / numbers as the title when you want to fetch the movie information based on the selected title. Better use the ID of your movie

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** Change your value attribute to  `value="<?php echo $row['Title']; ?>"`

**2nd :** Id attribute is unique for each element. remove it from option tag `id="film_id"`

```
 <option value="<?php echo $row['Title']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

change below line

```
<option value="director_movie1" id="film_id"><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></option>
```

with

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['Title']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></option>
```

Now you will get dynamic value different options also `id` can not have same value for all